Shift data by row if column null
I can do this by Python script the resulting dataset but wondering if it can be done within SQL Server query.
tableA



ID
parentID
CodeName




1
0
french


2
1
german


3
0
wilma


4
3
fred


5
2
british


6
0
bag



tableB



ID
ExpectedDuration
ChildID




1
5
6


2
2
4


3
7
5




SELECT
    tableA_2.CodeName AS Parent1Name
    , tableA_1.CodeName AS Parent2Name
    , tableA.CodeName AS Parent3Name
    , tableB.ExpectedDuration
FROM tableB 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA ON tableB.ChildID = table1.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS tableA_1 ON tableA.Parent_ID = tableA_1.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS tableA_2 ON tableA_1.Parent_ID = tableA_2.ID

The results of this based on how many levels each item has from tableB is



Parent1Name
Parent2Name
Parent3Name
ExpectedDuration




Null
Null
bag
5


Null
wilma
fred
2


french
german
british
7



and the results I would like to have is null shifted to the left so that data is like



Parent1Name
Parent2Name
Parent3Name
ExpectedDuration




bag
Null
Null
5


wilma
fred
Null
2


french
german
british
2



Looking to shift the data in the first 3 columns so that all the null values are in the rightmost column instead of the left.
Example Python code to do the same (might not be perfect but not concerned about this part)
headers = ['Parent1Name', 'Parent2Name', 'Parent3Name', 'Duration']  
newdata = []  
For row in Dataset:  
  level1=''  
  level2=''  
  level3=''  
  parent1 = row['Parent1Name']  
  parent2 = row['Parent2Name']  
  parent3 = row['Parent3Name']  
  duration = row['ExpectedDuration']  
  
  if parent1 ='' and parent2 ='':  
     level1 = parent3  
  elif parent1 = '':  
     level1 = parent2  
     level2 = parent3  
  else:  
    level 1 = parent1  
    level 2 = parent2  
    level 3 = parent3  
  newdata.append([level1, level2, level3, duration])  
createDataset(headers,newdata)  

I can put the first SQL query into a View so it wouldn't need to redo the joins when running another query to shift the data...  just not sure if this kind of data shift is possible.

I'm not convinced that you should do this in SQL. As a general principle, the data and any query results should directly represent the truth. In your desired results, what parent1 means changes for each row, that's a SQL Code Smell. This strikes me as a requirement for presentation of data to a human, and that should be done in the presentation layer of your application, not in the database / data layer.

Did any of the answers resolve your issue?

A more generalized approach is to:

Unpivot the source columns to be shifted.
Eliminate any null values.
Renumber the remaining values using the ROW_NUMBER() window function.
Pivot the data into the receiving columns

This approach can be easily expanded to handle any number of columns.
Although this can be done using SQL UNPIVOT and PIVOT operations, the syntax is sometimes awkward to work with. The following instead uses a VALUES subquery to unpivot the source columns into rows and conditional aggregation to pivot the renumbered rows back into columns. This is all wrapped up in a CROSS APPLY.
SELECT R.Parent1Name, R.Parent2Name, R.Parent3Name, B.ExpectedDuration
FROM tableB B
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS A ON B.ChildID = A.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS A1 ON A.ParentID = A1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS A2 ON A1.ParentID = A2.ID
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        MAX(CASE WHEN R.Renumbered = 1 THEN R.Value END) AS Parent1Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN R.Renumbered = 2 THEN R.Value END) AS Parent2Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN R.Renumbered = 3 THEN R.Value END) AS Parent3Name
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY V.Ordinal) AS Renumbered,
            V.Value
        FROM (
            VALUES
                (1, A2.CodeName),
                (2, A1.CodeName),
                (3, A.CodeName)
        ) V(Ordinal, Value)
        WHERE V.Value IS NOT NULL
    ) R
) R

Similar logic using UNPIVOT and PIVOT:
SELECT C.Parent1Name, C.Parent2Name, C.Parent3Name, B.ExpectedDuration
FROM tableB B
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS A ON B.ChildID = A.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS A1 ON A.ParentID = A1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA AS A2 ON A1.ParentID = A2.ID
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT PVT.[1] AS Parent1Name, PVT.[2] AS Parent2Name, PVT.[3] AS Parent3Name
    FROM (
        SELECT
            UNPVT.Value,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UNPVT.Col) AS Renumbered
        FROM (
            SELECT A2.CodeName AS [1], A1.CodeName AS [2], A.CodeName AS [3]
        ) S1
        UNPIVOT (
            Value
            FOR Col IN ([1], [2], [3])
        ) UNPVT
    ) S2
    PIVOT (
        MAX(S2.Value)
        FOR S2.Renumbered IN ([1], [2], [3])
    ) PVT
) C

Wrapping the unpivot/pivot operations up in an OUTER APPLY isolates the logic from the rest or your query, so that you do not need to worry about passing around extra columns. This logic also avoids inadvertent grouping of rows having the same values in the pivot step or mistakenly dropping entire rows that have no non-null values.
Results of both versions are identical:



Parent1Name
Parent2Name
Parent3Name
ExpectedDuration




bag
null
null
5


wilma
fred
null
2


french
german
british
7



See this db<>fiddle for a demo of both techniques.


Parent1Name: Takes the first non-null value from highest to lowest level (a2 → a1 → a).
Parent2Name: Only shows a value if there's at least one parent above it.
Parent3Name: Only shows a value if there are two parents above it.

SELECT
    COALESCE(a2.CodeName, a1.CodeName, a.CodeName) AS Parent1Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN a2.CodeName IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(a1.CodeName, a.CodeName)
        WHEN a1.CodeName IS NOT NULL THEN a.CodeName
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Parent2Name,
    CASE 
        WHEN a2.CodeName IS NOT NULL AND a1.CodeName IS NOT NULL THEN a.CodeName
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Parent3Name,
    b.ExpectedDuration
FROM tableB b
LEFT JOIN tableA a ON b.ChildID = a.ID 
LEFT JOIN tableA a1 ON a.parentID = a1.ID 
LEFT JOIN tableA a2 ON a1.parentID = a2.ID;

Output:



Parent1Name
Parent2Name
Parent3Name
ExpectedDuration




bag
Null
Null
5


wilma
fred
Null
2


french
german
british
7




Your query produces the expected result (upvoted), see this sample fiddle. Just one hint: You can remove the ELSE clauses of your CASE expressions because NULL is the default if no condition is satisfied.

There tableA is tree definition. Collect (pivot) this tree by recursive  query and join to tableB thru final leaf of the tree.
This method is quite similar to your algorithm in Python.
See example
with r as (
  select Id,ParentId
     ,codeName Parent1Name
     ,cast(null as varchar(50)) Parent2Name
     ,cast(null as varchar(50)) Parent3Name
  from tableA
  where ParentId=0
  union all
  select t.Id,r.id ParentId
     ,t.codeName Parent1Name
     ,r.Parent1Name Parent2Name
     ,r.Parent2Name Parent3Name
  from r inner join tableA t on r.Id=t.ParentId
)
select b.Id,r.Parent1Name,r.Parent2Name,r.Parent3Name
  ,b.ExpectedDuration 
from tableB b
inner join r on b.ChildId=r.Id ;





id
Parent1Name
Parent2Name
Parent3Name
ExpectedDuration




1
bag
null
null
5


2
fred
wilma
null
2


3
british
german
french
7



Details for recursion. Added step column to indicate data changes in recursion level.
On every level we shift values
Parent1Name->Parent2Name->Parent3Name
If tree deep is more than 3, we can add Parent3Name->Parent4Name ...->ParentXName in anchor an recursion part of query r.
with r as (
  select Id,ParentId
     ,codeName Parent1Name
     ,cast(null as varchar(50)) Parent2Name
     ,cast(null as varchar(50)) Parent3Name
--     ,cast(null as varchar(50)) Parent4Name
     ,1 step
  from tableA
  where ParentId=0
  union all
  select t.Id,r.id ParentId
     ,t.codeName Parent1Name
     ,r.Parent1Name Parent2Name
     ,r.Parent2Name Parent3Name
--   ,r.Parent3Name Parent4Name
     ,step+1 step
  from r inner join tableA t on r.Id=t.parentId
)
select * from r;




Id
ParentId
Parent1Name
Parent2Name
Parent3Name
step




1
0
french
null
null
1


3
0
wilma
null
null
1


6
0
bag
null
null
1


4
3
fred
wilma
null
2


2
1
german
french
null
2


5
2
british
german
french
3



fiddle
